# Split array to multiple arrays using a collection of boolean masks

Tags: python, numpy

Given a data array of shape (m,n) and array of bool masks of the same shape. Is there a way to apply the following routine without a loop:

1. Apply each column of the masks array to the data array obtaining a sub-array
2. Store all sub-arrays

Here is a loop solution

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [np.nan,5,6]
])

masks = np.array([
    [True, True, True],
    [False, True, True]
])

arrays = []

for i in range(masks.shape[1]):
    mask_i = masks[:, i]
    arr_i = arr[mask_i, :]
    arrays.append(arr_i)
```

Explored potential solutions:

1. `np.take` Doesn't work because the `indices` param requires homogeneous shape, while in some cases we can take fewer and in other more rows.
2. Fancy indexing `arr[masks,:]` doesn't work with higher dimensional masks
3. `np.split` Doesn't work because it can split only to complete non-overlapping sub-arrays

Comment: What is your actual goal? I think this may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: To split the array without using a loop for the sake of speed maybe?

Comment: is the use of `arr_i = arr[mask_i, i:]`, esp the `í:` part, with a Boolean `i`?  Boolean or not `i:` doesn't work for array

Comment: `arr[mask)` produces a (5,) shape

Comment: @hpaulj you're right that i: is an extra bit not required for the isolated problem, corrected to :

Comment: A list of arrays always requires a list operation!

Comment: @hpaulj here I would disagree, you can have arrays of arrays which are simply ndarrays and there are np functions which perform such operations

Comment: @Konstantin, object dtype arrays are constructed the same way, with references/pointers to arrays. Math is still at list comprehension speeds, and hit-or-miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the sub arrays as instances (like specified elements inside list) and it is okay to have them all stored in one np array, then this snippet could be helpful:

```
arr = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [np.nan,5,6]]) # (m, n)

masks = np.array([
    [True, True, True],
    [False, True, True]]) # (m, n)

arr_rep = np.repeat(arr[np.newaxis, :, :], masks.shape[1], axis=0) # (n, m, n)
masks = np.transpose(masks) # (n, m)

arrays = arr_rep[masks]
```

So arrays will have the masks-True rows from arr.